# Creating a CSV from date list output in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I am running the following script in Azure Databricks:

```
def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

start_dt = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
end_dt = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=2)


for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    df = print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    display(df)
```

When I print or display the output I get a nice list of dates like this:

```
2021-04-19
2021-04-20
2021-04-21
2021-04-22
2021-04-23
2021-04-24
2021-04-25
2021-04-26
2021-04-27
2021-04-28
2021-04-29
2021-04-30
2021-05-01
2021-05-02
```

I need to use that list to create a CSV that I will subsequently load into Azure Storage. Any idea how I can create the CSV from the query in the Notebook?

Comment: in your case the CSV consists of one column, so you can write this just as a normal text file.  Uploading to Azure Storage depends on how you access it - via mounts, by full URL, etc.  Please provide more details on what is the actual problem is

Comment: The actual problem is how to take the output of a list generated in Databricks and convert it into a text file, preferably comma delimited. The reason it is a problem is because I need to use the output here (a list of dates) as a lookup table in Data Factory to recursively run a pipeline against each date in the list. The way I do this at the moment is to use CSV lookup tables to trigger the pipeline from the specified start date until the specified end date.